# Rails assets don't have Cache Control headers with Puma on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, heroku, cache-control, puma

For some reason, my Rails assets won't get Cache Control headers sent when I've got them being served up from Heroku using the Puma server.

I have `config.public_file_server.headers = { 'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800' }` set in my `production.rb`, and when I run the app on my local machine, this works fine:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=31536000
Etag: "fdffdae515ab907046e7deed6a567968ab3e689f8505a281988bf6892003ff92"
X-Request-Id: 065e704c-1bea-428c-9c40-3cd6b6e4330a
X-Runtime: 0.002411
```

However, when I deploy to Heroku, I get the following headers:

```
Server: Cowboy
Date: Sat, 10 Jun 2017 18:56:26 GMT
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

This seems slightly odd, surprisingly enough. I'm really quite lost to understand why this is happening. I'm using the Puma web server as is recommended by Heroku themselves - here's my Procfile:

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

And here's my puma.rb in config:

```
# Puma can serve each request in a thread from an internal thread pool.
# The `threads` method setting takes two numbers a minimum and maximum.
# Any libraries that use thread pools should be configured to match
# the maximum value specified for Puma. Default is set to 5 threads for minimum
# and maximum, this matches the default thread size of Active Record.
#
threads_count = ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 }.to_i
threads threads_count, threads_count

# Specifies the `port` that Puma will listen on to receive requests, default is 3000.
#
port        ENV.fetch("PORT") { 3000 }

# Specifies the `environment` that Puma will run in.
#
environment ENV.fetch("RAILS_ENV") { "development" }

# Specifies the number of `workers` to boot in clustered mode.
# Workers are forked webserver processes. If using threads and workers together
# the concurrency of the application would be max `threads` * `workers`.
# Workers do not work on JRuby or Windows (both of which do not support
# processes).

workers ENV.fetch("WEB_CONCURRENCY") {2}

# Use the `preload_app!` method when specifying a `workers` number.
# This directive tells Puma to first boot the application and load code
# before forking the application. This takes advantage of Copy On Write
# process behavior so workers use less memory. If you use this option
# you need to make sure to reconnect any threads in the `on_worker_boot`
# block.

preload_app!

# The code in the `on_worker_boot` will be called if you are using
# clustered mode by specifying a number of `workers`. After each worker
# process is booted this block will be run, if you are using `preload_app!`
# option you will want to use this block to reconnect to any threads
# or connections that may have been created at application boot, Ruby
# cannot share connections between processes.

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection if defined?(ActiveRecord)
end

# Allow puma to be restarted by `rails restart` command.
plugin :tmp_restart
```

Anyone got any ideas? Incidentally, contrary to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054337/rails-cache-control-headers-not-applying-to-all-files), it doesn't make any difference which file type the served file is - none of them have cache-control set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

Turns out, without Heroku telling you obviously, if you want to use caching in the asset pipeline, you need to add the `rails_12factor` gem to your Gemfile:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

As soon as I added the `rails_12factor` gem, things started working fine :)

Answer (score 2):

With **Rails 5**, you can simply take advantage of `ActionDispatch::Static` to set custom HTTP headers to serve assets:

```
# config/environments/production.rb

config.public_file_server.headers = {
  'Cache-Control' => 'public, s-maxage=31536000, max-age=15552000',
  'Expires' => "#{1.year.from_now.to_formatted_s(:rfc822)}"
}
```

Source: https://blog.bigbinary.com/2015/10/31/rails-5-allows-setting-custom-http-headers-for-assets.html#rails-5-saves-the-day